# Please correct highlighted fragment

Tags: grammar

a massive collection of conversations was created in the same way **as when** collecting postcards or telegrams or letters

Comment: How does one collect a conversation?

Comment: Hello, ana. What makes you think this is incorrect (and in what way)? One could argue that it's a deleted form of  'A massive collection of conversations was created in the same way as _is seen_ when _one is_ collecting postcards or telegrams or letters.' And then argue about its acceptability in various registers.

Comment: @Killing Time An acceptable broadening / metonymy (obviously a collection of recordings of ...).

Comment: Thank you. I was just unsure of the grammar construct of this comparison. I'm finishing my thesis and getting confused easily:)

Comment: fragment here: ‘Tweeting the Olympics’, a collaborative research project between the BBC World Service and the Open University (OU), resulting the collection of 5,509,928 about the London 2012 Olympic and Paralympic games. This ‘global conversation’, (in BBC terms), “a massive collection of conversations was created in the same way as is seen when one is collecting postcards or telegrams or letters."